# How to make a game without OOP?

Tags: architecture, software-engineering, oop

I am currenty studying game development and practicing making games.

I use a lot of OOP in my games. For example, each missile that is shot is an instance of a `Missile` object, and added to a list of `Missile` objects. Each tank in the game is a `Tank` object. Etc.

The entire design of the program is based on this. For instance, having a list of `Missile` objects allows me every frame to move the missiles, draw them, etc. And having an instance of a `Tank` object for every tank allows me to check for each tank if it collides with something, etc.

It's hard for me to imagine how a game (which is more complex than Pac-Man) could be programmed in a non-OO language. (With no disrespect to non-OO programmers of course). Not only in terms of how long it will take, but mostly in terms of how a game could be designed this way.

I can't imagine designing a game without using object oriented programming, because my entire understanding of how to design a game-program is based on OOP.

I would like ask: Today, are there any games that aren't programmed using OOP, in a similiar fashion to what I described above? Are there any 'professionl' games that don't use OOP as a major factor in the development process?

If so, could you give me an idea of how, for example, collision detection between a tank and N number of missiles could be implemented, without OOP?

Comment: Is this a philosophical question? Even if you don't call your tanks "objects", you're probably going to want "entities", "actors", "agents", "structs" or just *some other name* for the same idea, which is a collection of attributes and behaviours that make up a rotating cuboid thing with a turret that can shoot things, called a tank. Programming languages will have different ways of formalising this same idea, but in the end, it's going to be a tank.

Comment: Many games use a Component-based system as this answer describes: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/31491/9366

Comment: This is both exceedingly broad (which you could possibly fix by narrowing the scope) and not really specific to game development (since building software without OO techniques is not something a game developer would give you a better answer than any other software developer would), which makes it off topic here, I'm afraid.

Comment: It may be suitable for StackOverflow, or you can check out the [help] to find a selection of sites that are game-development specific (like GDNet) that would permit this sort of broad, discussion-oriented topic. Good luck!

Answer (score 16):

> I can't imagine designing a game without using object oriented programming, because my entire understanding of how to design a game-program is based on OOP.

Then it will probably be good for you to try writing some programs in non-OO style. Even if you discover that this is not pragmatic for you, you'll probably learn a lot along the way that will help you in the future.

OO style is pretty well-suited for games because games are almost always about manipulation of stateful objects. A laser beam hits the robot and the state of the robot changes while its identity remains the same.

However it is possible to program games in a *functional* style. In a functional style, state doesn't change per se. Objects are immutable. Rather than changing objects, you ask the question *how would the universe be different if I changed this?* and then produce an entire new universe that has the changed property. Of course, you can re-use a lot of the previously existing universe *because it is immutable*.

In functional programming every function must compute its return value solely from the information passed in; there's no reading from "global state".

If you do this, the fundamental problem you will have to get through your head is that *every update is non-destructive*. When the laser hits the robot you don't change the robot's state. Ultimately you compute an entirely new universe identical to the old universe except that the robot has a different state; if you need that old universe, it's still there, unchanged.

This series of blog articles has more thoughts on writing games in a functional style:

http://prog21.dadgum.com/23.html

This article specifically addresses your "shell hits a tank" question:

http://prog21.dadgum.com/189.html

In fact, just read the whole blog. There's good stuff there and the articles are short.

Answer (score 13):

Any object-oriented program can be refactored to a procedural program by replacing all classes with structures and converting all member-functions into stand-alone function which take the object which would be `this` as an argument.

So

```
 missile.setVelocity(100);
```

becomes

```
 setMissileVelocity(missile, 100);
```

or when that function is trivial, you just do

```
 missile.velocity = 100;
```

The main difference between object-oriented programming and procedural programming is how you treat your data. In OOP, data is *smart*. It manages and manipulates itself. But in procedural programming, data is *dumb*. It doesn't do anything on its own and needs to be manipulated from the outside.

When you even consider structures too object-oriented, you can replace one array of structures with multiple arrays, one for everything which would be a variable of a missile. So

```
struct Missile {
     int x;
     int y;
     int velocity;
}

Missile missiles[256];
```

becomes

```
int missileX[256];
int missileY[256];
int missileVelocities[256];
```

In this design, a function which does an operation involving multiple attributes on the same missile would now take an array index instead of a reference to a structure. Its implementation would look like this:

```
function updateMissilePosition(int index) {
     missileX[index] += missileVelocity[index];
}
```

Comment: But `missile` is an instance of an object. In non-OOP, there are no instances, am I correct? If so, how could you do setMissileVelocity(missile,100)?

Comment: @user3150201 You aren't entirely correct. Most non-OOP languages (and I would argue just about any which is suitable for serious game development) supports structures. A structure is kind of like a class, just that it contains nothing except public variables. So it would allow you to create a type `Missile`, which is a structure with several fields, like `x`, `y`, `angle` and `velocity`.

Comment: @user3150201 Updated answer with a section about how to do it without structures.

Comment: Nice answer Philipp, although, I don't understand why would one doesn't want to program Object-Oriented. It's really hard to read non-OOP languages, and can be fustrating. The code can become a mess in no time.

Comment: @Zhafur You are aware that your statement is a massive flamebait, are you?

Comment: I am sorry, did not suppose to flame, it's just my point of view.

Comment: @Philipp for one, as you asked, most of those kinda games were developed in an era when OOP languages were not introduced (or at least were not common). and second there are some people who think exactly opposite of your. for example see why linux is developed in C instead of C++.

Comment: @Ali.S I think you meant to highlight Zhafur instead of me. I am trying to stay as neutral on this issue as possible.

Comment: @Zhafur yep, just made a mistake :|

Comment: @Ali.S thank you for the background information, now I know why you want it. :)

Answer (score 7):

I do it as follows:

- All OOP classes/methods have access to `this`. In order to utilise `this` in a non-OO approach, simply pass in whichever instance (see next point) `this` should be, as the first parameter.
- Now, as for instances, you can pass `struct`s into your functions as `this`, but I find the best way to achieve good cache performance for objects which are prolific, such as entities or particles, is to simply pass a single index into several arrays of primitives or small `struct`s. So this index is used for each individual data member of the original class. So for instance if you had

...

```
class Entity //let's say you had 100 instances of this
{
   int a;
   char b;
   function foo() 
   {
      .../*can access 'this' herein*/
   }
}
```

You would replace that with

```
int a[100];
char b[100];
function foo(int index);
```

So that you are now passing an index into the function to get what would usually be `this`.

Bear in mind that you may wish to use either arrays of primitives as above, *or* arrays of `struct`s, depending on how best to interleave your data for good cache locality (locality of reference). Of course, decent cache performance relies on a lot more than this -- particularly, what language / platform you are writing your code on -- but even in VM-based, dynamically-allocated languages like Java, large linear arrays of primitives tend to display better performance characteristics than object instances. The main reason for this is that objects are accessed by reference and this means you are jumping all over memory to access data -- inefficient compared to accessing primitives contiguously from a large array.

For more information on building entities etc. as array of structs or primitives, see [Mick West's Evolve your Hierarchy](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers you may want to know how to do polymorphism in a procedural language.

There are two approaches:

**Storing the type**

In this case the struct has a field for the type identifier, probably an enum, that's checked using a `switch` statement when type specific action needs to be done.

The other way is:

**Storing [function pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer)**

You didn't mentioned which programming language you have experience in, but in various languages they are also called callbacks, delegates, events or high order functions or simply function objects.

In this case you won't store a type, but store a pointer/reference to a function that does the particular action. When type specific action needs to be done, you simply call this function. This one looks much like the ordinary virtual methods.

By allowing setting each function independently you get the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) free.

---

Regarding your last paragraph with the collision detection. I think you probably have multiple kinds of tanks and you have multiple kinds of missiles, and each combination can potentially have a different outcome when they collide. If this is what you look for, you have a problem that's not yet solved by even OOP languages: multiple dispatch and multi-methods that can have multiple `this` parameters of different types. For this problem there again two alternatives:

- Nested switches for each combination of tank and missile.
- Two dimensional dispatch arrays, which contain pointers to functions for each combination of tank and missile.