# How can I cast a std::shared_ptr<Component> to the correct derived class?

Tags: c++, component-based

I'm trying to implement a component based design for a game I'm making. I decided to write it in C++, but I'm not very good at it. Coming from a Java background I encountered a problem when trying to manage the `std::vector` for the components. Right now each entity has a vector of components that can be of different derived classes such as "Transform Component" which has an `x` and `y` field that I will access later. From what I've read I have to use a `std::shared_ptr` for each component, and that has worked fine except when I retrieve a component and try to cast it I start getting errors.

The code looks like this:

Component.hpp

```
class Component
{
public:
    virtual ComponentType getType() = 0;

    virtual ~Component() { }
};
```

Transfrom.hpp

```
class Transform : public Component
{
public:
    float x, y;

    virtual ComponentType getType() { return ComponentType::TRANSFORM; }
};
```

Entity.hpp

```
class Entity
{
public:
    Entity() : m_components() { }

    Component& getComponent(ComponentType type);
    void addComponent(std::shared_ptr<Component> comp);
    bool hasComponent(ComponentType type);

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>> m_components;
};
```

And when I try to use it:

```
// This gives an error!
Transform comp = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Transform>(entity.getComponent(ComponentType::TRANSFORM));
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your implementation is a bit off of the other Entity-Component systems I've seen. I recommend taking a look at [EntityX](https://github.com/alecthomas/entityx). It should give a good idea of what a working implementation looks like.

You could also read these which may help:

[Role of systems in entity systems architecture](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31473/role-of-systems-in-entity-systems-architecture)

[Component - Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html)

[Understanding Component-Entity-Systems](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/understanding-component-entity-systems-r3013)

As for some specific code critiques:

- Using templates to manage your component types, not an `enum`. This will make for cleaner code. I'd only use an `enum` (or any numerical type or string) if you were implementing scripting or any runtime-based component system, but that's a whole different issue. Templates just offer better type safety.
- Using `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::shared_ptr`. If you're making copies of entites for whatever reason, you don't want them to share a pointer to the same component. If you're not copying them, you're wasting performance.
- Using an ID for an entity and a central system (that holds components tied to a specific ID) instead of `Entity` objects that hold the components themselves.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction I was actually a bit confused as the difference between component based and entity-component based. Just an inquiry on the critiques, I'm not much of an expert on templates but could you direct me on how I could use them for the component types?

Comment: Take a look at EntityX's source code for a working example it. I haven't taken a full look at it, but I've tried it before and it uses template types. There are a few ways to do it, but with `typeid` you could do something like this: `template<typename T> hasComponent() { for (auto comp : components) if (typeid(comp)) == typeid(T) return true; return false; }` so you could simply do: `if (entity_manager.doesEntityHaveComponent<SomeComponent>(id)) { .... }`'.

Comment: I recommend researching and learning how to use RTTI. It should make understanding how to use templates for component identification much easier.

Answer (score 0):

`std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Transform>` doesn't return a `Transform`, it returns a `std::shared_ptr<Transform>` so your cast should look something like:

```
std::shared_ptr<Transform> comp = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Transform>(entity.getComponent(ComponentType::TRANSFORM));
```

Also, if the compiler can statically deduce the type of your r-value you could just use the auto keyword:

```
auto comp = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Transform>(entity.getComponent(ComponentType::TRANSFORM));
```