# How can I use multiple meshes per entity without breaking one component of a single type per entity?

Tags: architecture, component-based

We are just switching from a hierarchy based game engine to a component based game engine. My problem is that when I load a model which has a hierarchy of meshes, and the way I understand, is that an entity in a component based system can not have multiple components of the same type, but I need a "meshComponent" for each mesh in a model. So how could I solve this problem.

On this site they implemented a Component based game engine:
http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/

Comment: I think this is too localized.

Comment: I think its a general question. Can a game object have multiple instance of the same component?

Comment: Yeah, it *could've* been, if it was asked like that. To me it seems as if he was looking for an answer to a very specific problem.

Comment: "...entity in a component based system can not have multiple components of the same type..." - why not?

Comment: I don’t think it’s too localised. For instance in UE3, `SkeletalMeshActor` only has one `SkeletalMeshComponent`. It’s a common problem that can be addressed in many different ways.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your Position component could have a "parent/children" logic, where any Entity with a Position may have a parent and their position is relative to their parent. Instead of having several meshs on the same entity, you can make more than one entity, each with its own mesh and link them together. You can even make the children entities listen to their parent events (or whatever system you have for communication between entities) and react accordingly.

Comment: So I have a hierarchy of entitys and these entitys have componends and are linked togheter. Is it then still a Component based game engine =)

Comment: @MathiasHölzl is that a question? This kind of hierarchy is not the same as the problematic hierarchy in OOP. This is just a graphical hierarchy, children Entities won't inherit functionality from their parent and give you trouble, this is usually done anyway (having a tree of stuff to render). You can also go with Asakeron answer to your problem, having a list of Meshs, I don't see how that's problematic. Maybe I don't understand your question?

Comment: -1 Not sure if that's really the way to go. If what you need is a component handling a hierarchy of meshes, why not having a `ModelComponent` that contains a hierarchy of meshes? Splitting an entity just for that sounds like the wrong solution to the problem. See Asakeron's and Byte56's answers.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou I don't see why using more than one Entity would be wrong, it seems like the a good solution for me. I just wanted to give a different alternative to having a list of meshs, though I agree that a list of meshs would also be a good solution.

Comment: @LukeB. Because this group of mesh can correspond to one entity as a whole, with components that depend on this e.g. AI, sound, physics... By doing this you end up with a scene graph and all its quirks.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou He could also put his meshes on the same file using a 3D program. I think that if he needs to separate them its because each mesh has different behavior (be it textures/materials/whatever), I think it's easier to do that as separate entities instead of a list of meshes, because then you will need a list of textures, a list of materials, a list of shaders, after that you might as well use an entity for each mesh.

Comment: @LukeB. You're missing my point here. In some cases it would be OK to split in several entities, if they are conceptually several entities. But if you're doing this just because of a design limitation (e.g. being able to have only one `MeshComponent` per entity, or the lack of a full-fledged `ModelComponent`), then I advocate improving the design instead of working around it.

Comment: @LaurentCouvidou Ah, you are right. If the problem is in the design, there are better solutions.

Answer (score 8):

Your meshComponent may contain a list of meshes. I'm not sure how you are implementing your engine, but a system could easily iterate over all meshes and simply draw them.

Comment: A mesh has also components like transform, physic, graphic...

Comment: So a mesh is an entity? Or is everything a component? The way I see it, transform, physic and graphic should be components in the entity not in the mesh, a mesh is just a description of vertices.

Comment: Yeah it should be a component but components can not have components so its hard to implement the hierarchy of the model.

Comment: I believe you should provide more information on how you intend to build your engine in order to get better answers. Entity Component Systems can be implemented in many ways, check [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4898/are-there-existing-foss-component-based-frameworks/4966#4966) by Kylotan for more information on that.

Answer (score 4):

I would create my mesh component with a list of mesh objects. Each mesh object has the mesh data along with an offset. When drawing, the drawing system takes the position from the position component, then draws each mesh in the mesh component at position + offset.

You can have multiple meshes inside your mesh component, while still saying with a single mesh component per entity.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: By making the *component* consist of multiple meshes to begin with.**

I agree with Asakeron/Byte56/Laurent in that another level of indirection is needed between the mesh/material pairs, and the entity itself. Instead of looking at the GraphicsComponent as vertices and materials, think of it as a blob of pixels on the final raster - how it/they get there is an implementation detail and nothing more.

I thought about this a lot for my project and I think the optimal solution is to make the GraphicsComponent a much higher level component, encompassing much of the functionality of the traditional 'Model' object - because this functionality isn't optional! To render those polygons a lot more than just the buffer data and the shader is needed, such as:

- Position which you have mentioned
- Skinning/Animation data
- The Current Pass (e.g. if using two pass alpha)
- Shadow casting information (if you are doing it)
- Information on *how* and when to update the material
- Culling functionality

And thats just for 3D assets, without considering particle systems, billboards, etc. But all of it is pertinent only to the graphics/rendering code - it doesn't affect the physics, sound or scripting, so it makes sense it should sit in the Graphics/Rendering component.

I ended up with:

```
Model : Entity, IHasGraphicsComponent, IHasSkeleton, IHasAnimationStore     //This is the 'game object' - it is passed to the GraphicsController
    ModelComponent : GraphicsComponent                      //This is the actual graphics component, used by the GraphicsController in the context of the game object.
        ModelComponentPart : GraphicsComponent              //This is also a graphics component
            Mesh                                        //These are implementation details
            Material
        ModelComponentPart : GraphicsComponent
            Mesh
            Material
    Skeleton
    Animations
```

In this:

- Model is any game asset that has a graphics component.
- The ModelComponent is analogous to the traditional Model and in fact, is, for 3D assets. The GraphicsComponent controller (if you use the Model-View-Controller pattern) is responsible for figuring out what type of graphics asset it is and drawing it correctly (note that ModelComponent is a subclass of GraphicsComponent).

There were also a couple of compromises in mine for simplicity and backwards compatabilitys sake, such as each GraphicsComponent is also an Entity, and Entity stores Position data directly so its only calculated in one place, but the idea is the same: **GraphicsComponent handles what is needed to draw the item - all of what is needed - not just what comes from the modeller.**